# Сhange the render texture resolution(Resize)

Tags: unity-game-engine

please tell me, is there some faster method to reduce the resolution of the Render texture other than: copy to texture2D after creating the required resolution render texture and into it Graphics.blit image?Example: from a 1024x1024 Render texture , reduce the resolution to 512x512 . Thank you in advance

Comment: Like [Texture2d.Resize](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Resize.html)? Don't know if it's faster though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can graphics.Blit directly between RenderTextures, no need for an intermediate Texture2D stage.

Comment: and how to use graphics.Blit to copy the render texture of a larger size to a smaller one while saving the image (I just need to reduce the quality, because in RAM to store 2048 texture is too difficult and exceeds the memory limit)

Comment: blit respects sizes of both textures, just make the new one smaller and blit like there's no tomorrow

Comment: thanks for the help(voice put, but because of the low reputation it is not displayed)

Comment: @Stelette think you should be able to accept the answer as a poster, its a checkbox not a vote